# VB.NET assignment of object default property value

Tags: operator-overloading, variable-assignment, default-value, assignment-operator

This is a very weird question, you may find it to be.
I'm working on a huge Migration project of VB6 to VB.NET 2010. As part in VB6 we have a constant defined as NullString = ""
In .NET too its migrated on similar lines and used. 
The issue we have is when comparing a value from a RecordSet (Its just a wrapper around DataTable) being compared with this NullString we get error for comparing.
As the project is under active development we have to rely of Migration Tool (VB MIgration Partner) which understands few Pragma but not too advanced.
I created a class (NullStringClass) and overloaded "=" and "<>" operators, it sorted my issue of comparison.
But at places we have someVar = NullString, where someVar being a string variable. Now, I get error that can not convert from NullStringClass to string.
I tried to overload ToString method and returned "" and also put an attribute on class like below:

```
<System.Reflection.DefaultMember("Value")> _
Public Class NullStringClass
```

The property is defined as:

```
Public Property Value() As String
    Get
        Return ""
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)

    End Set
End Property
```

But it still throws exception.
As far as I know this should have sorted my issue, but no luck.
I still get same error.
So, my question is for same.
Is there any way I can convert that NullString variable to be a class and use Operator Overloading for different comparisons (including Null and Nothing) and also use as normal assignment to string variables?
E.g. means

```
Dim s as String
s = NullString
```

Should work as well as below should work:

```
If rsData("MyField").Value <> NullString Then
'Note: rsData("MyField").Value is DbNull
```

Here is the sample for operator overloading (if anyone is interested)

```
Public Shared Operator <>(ByVal mmyVal As Object, ByVal objVal As NullStringClass) As Boolean
    If TypeOf mmyVal Is String Then
        Return (Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(mmyVal))
    Else 'If TypeOf mmyVal Is Object Then
        Return (Not IsDBNull(mmyVal))
    End If
End Operator
```

Thanks,
Nik

Comment: Just though another idea. Keeping NullString as string (not write a class), but Overload <> operator for String class through Extension Method. Is it possible?

Comment: You are trying to turn .net into VB6 going down this route, a bad idea on so many levels. On top of that "" is not null and and it's not DBNull, making them equivalent is simply perpertuating ignorance.

Comment: The application is being migrated because Microsoft has stopped supporting VB6 :-)
Another brand new web application is on its way to replace this one. 
The only reason to migrate this app is to have it go for another couple of years.

Comment: Instead of your null string, why not use String.Empty ?  This is provided by .net for this sort of purpose.

Comment: Well thats what the value of NullString variable is. But issue is when I compare that with DbNull it throws exception. Hence I needed some class to handle both String as well as DbNull i.e. object. Pls see my answer :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had put this question after struggling for 2 days and scratching my head for making that "=" work. (Operator Overloading was working fine within 1 hr).
The solution to get "s = NullString" right was to put implicit operator for my NullStringClass.

```
Public Shared Widening Operator CType(ByVal obj As String) As NullStringClass
    Return New NullStringClass()
End Operator

Public Shared Narrowing Operator CType(ByVal obj As NullStringClass) As String
    Return String.Empty
End Operator
```

Although only Narrowing Operator was enough, I had put Widening as well (will be removed in production code as its not required).
Hope this is helpful for someone like me :-)

Answer (score 1):

In vb.net, a storage location of type `string` which holds a `null` or uninitialized value is semantically different from a null string.  If you wish to compare such a storage location to another string which is known not to be null, and have such comparison simply return false if the storage location is null (rather than throwing an exception), you could write the expression as `"Whatever".Equals(storageLocation)`.  If you wish to compare two strings, either or both of which may be null, and have null strings compare equal to each other but not to anything else (including an empty string), you may use `String.Equals(string1, string2)`.  If you wish to determine whether a string is null or empty, you may use `String.IsNullorEmpty(theString)`.  If you wish to perform a comparison in such fashion that a null string is regarded as empty, you could write your own static comparison that would perform a comparison in that way, or you could write a function which would, given a `string`, return the passed-in string if non-null, and otherwise return `String.Empty`.

Hopefully, one of the above is what you're after.  Note that they have nothing to do with what VB6 calls a "default property", but your question doesn't seem to be asking about VB6 properties (and the related distinctions between `Let` and `Set`.

**ADDENDUM**

If you want a string type which can mostly be used like an ordinary string, but will default to an empty string rather than `Nothing`, you may be able to use something like this (incomplete, but should be a good start)

```
Public Structure SafeString
    Implements IComparable(Of SafeString), IEquatable(Of SafeString)

    Dim _St As String

    Sub New(St As String)
        _St = St
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return If(_St, "")
    End Function

    Public Overrides Function GetHashCode() As Integer
        Return If(_St, "").GetHashCode()
    End Function

    Public Overrides Function Equals(obj As Object) As Boolean
        If obj Is Nothing OrElse Not (TypeOf (obj) Is SafeString) Then Return False
        Return If(_St, "") = If(CType(obj, SafeString)._St, "")
    End Function

    Public Function CompareTo(other As SafeString) As Integer Implements System.IComparable(Of SafeString).CompareTo
        Return If(_St, "").CompareTo(If(other._St, ""))
    End Function

    Public Overloads Function Equals(other As SafeString) As Boolean Implements System.IEquatable(Of SafeString).Equals
        Return If(_St, "") = If(other._St, "")
    End Function

    Public Shared Widening Operator CType(st As String) As SafeString
        Dim ret As New SafeString
        ret._St = st
        Return ret
    End Operator

    Public Shared Widening Operator CType(safeSt As SafeString) As String
        Return If(safeSt._St, "")
    End Operator

    Function Length() As Integer
        Return If(_St, "").Length()
    End Function
    Function SubString(startIndex As Integer) As String
        Return If(_St, "").Substring(startIndex, Length)
    End Function
    Function SubString(startIndex As Integer, length As Integer) As String
        Return If(_St, "").Substring(startIndex, length)
    End Function
```

You'll notice a very common pattern `If(_St, "")`.  That function will either use _St if it's not null, or an empty string if it is.  It doesn't support all the methods `String` does, but if you need any methods that don't work yet, you should be able to follow the pattern shown by `Length`, etc.  Assignments and comparisons between `String` and `SafeString` should work as expected, except that `Object.Equals` will not regard any `String` as being equal to any `SafeString` (there's no way to change the behavior of the `String` override to make a string compare equal to an object of any other type; if `"Test".Equals(New SafeString("Test"))` is going to compare false, then `(New SafeString("Test")).Equals("Test")` must do likewise.

Comment: Apologies for late reply. But all this apply if I'm writing new code, but for Migration, unfortunately, I cant :-(
Hence I had to work with implicit operators.